# ValueError: unconverted data remains al convertir una cadena a datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, datetime

## Importo la librería

```
import datetime
```

## Consulto y traigo la fecha

```
miFecha.set(BBDDEscuela[6])
c=miFecha
Calculo_Dias(c)
miConexion.commit()
```

## Función para restar las dos fechas

```
def Calculo_Dias(b):
    a = datetime.datetime.today()
    f = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(b.get()), '%d/%m/%y')
    miDias.set((a-f).days)
```

## Me aparece este error

> ValueError: unconverted data remains: 90

`b` es una `StringVar` cuyo contenido en este caso es `"09/07/1990"`

Comment: ¿`b` es una `StringVar`? Haz `print(b.get())` antes de `a = datetime.datetime.today()` y muestra que te imprime. Posiblemente estás pasando algo como "20/03/1990" y en ese caso tu formato es inválido.

Comment: 09/07/1990 esto es lo que me pasa, como debe ser el formato?

Comment: Agradezco mucho su ayuda, estoy comenzando en Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error:

> ValueError: unconverted data remains:

ocurre cuando el formato pasado a `datetime.datetime.strptime` es inicialmente correcto, pero tras parsear la cadena de acuerdo al formato quedan caracteres remanentes en ella que no han sido convertidos.

En este caso la cadena es:

```
"09/07/1990"
```

y el formato es:

```
'%d/%m/%y'
```

el problema es que `y` indica el año mediante **dos caracteres** añadiendo un cero a la izquierda si es necesario **sin la centena**, es decir en vez de "1990" espera "90". Esto hace que al parsear la cadena se quede con `19` como año y queda `"90"` en la cadena sin parsear. Como que queden caracteres sin parsear suele significar que el formato o la fecha son incorrectos (como en este caso) se lanza una excepción.

> ```
> >>> datetime.datetime.strptime("09/07/1990", '%d/%m/%y')
> ValueError: unconverted data remains: 90
> ```

El código correcto es `Y` (año con las centenas) no `y`:

> ```
> >>> datetime.datetime.strptime("09/07/1990", '%d/%m/%Y')
> datetime.datetime(1990, 7, 9, 0, 0
> ```

Para más información ver:

- [strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias ya la probe y funciono, muchas gracias